# executing a scheduler

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I feel a bit silly, but been reading up examples here and other places to address my problem of "Deleting a large amount of records", and it seems like a scheduler is the best option.

So I wrote:

```
 global class sharedeletebatch Implements Database.batchable<sobject>
{

     global final string query;
     global sharedeletebatch(string q){

          query=q;
     }

     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
     }
     global  void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<SObject> scope){
         delete scope;

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }


}
```

and

```
global class deleteaccountsharebatch implements Schedulable {

public deleteaccountsharebatch()
{
        string str='select id from AccountShare where lastmodifiedbyid =\'0050P000007Kfy2\' limit 10000';
sharedeletebatch bdt=new sharedeletebatch(str);
Database.executeBatch(bdt);
system.debug(bdt);  
}


global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
{
    System.schedule('Hourly', '0 0 * * * ?', new deleteaccountsharebatch() );  
}
```

}

My goal is just delete a bit of accountshares every hour or so in my test org forever, but how do I actually 'run' this scheduler?

I also tried running this in debug anonymous window and it only ran once:

```
string str='select id from AccountShare where lastmodifiedbyid=\'0050P000007Kfy2\' limit 10000';
sharedeletebatch bdt=new sharedeletebatch(str);
Database.executeBatch(bdt);
system.debug(bdt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute the batch from the execute method of the scheduler, not the constructor.

modify your execute method of scheduler class to this:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC)
{

string str='select id from AccountShare where lastmodifiedbyid=\'0050P000007Kfy2\' limit 10000';
sharedeletebatch bdt=new sharedeletebatch(str);
Database.executeBatch(bdt);
system.debug(bdt);  
}
```

And then run the below script from the anonymous window once.

```
deleteaccountsharebatch m = new deleteaccountsharebatch();
String sch = '0 0 * * * ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Hourly Job', sch, m);
```

Comment: interesting. Will give a shot and report back!

Comment: hmmm the batch is running every hour, but im getting First error: [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped. Wonder if the query is too big?

Comment: that just basically means what you are doing in batch is taking way too much time. Try reducing the scope of the batch.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to even implement `Schedulable` to run a batch each hour. There is a method called `system.scheduleBatch` which will do the trick nicely here:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    system.scheduleBatch(this, 'Batch Name ' + Datetime.now().format(), 5);
}
```

You might consider implementing some `Hierarchy Custom Setting` to allow you to toggle the chaining on/off. Regardless, you will need some sort of `Boolean` to control it if you want any hope of testing, since you can only run the batch once in a test. For example your batch might look something like:

```
if (AccountShareSettings__c.getOrgDefaults().ShouldChainBatches__c)
{
    system.scheduleBatch(...);
}
```